# Windows 2008 R2 & Infiniband SRP

Tags: windows

Mellanox has removed support for SRP from Windows, http://www.mellanox.com/related-docs/prod_software/MLNX_WinVPI_ReleaseNotes.txt

I am trying to move from iSCSI to Infiniband with SRP. How does one use SRP with Infiniband on Windows? Can the [OFED](https://www.openfabrics.org/-download-windows-installer-.html) software be used?

I'm using a MHQH29C-XTR card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the OpenFabrics drivers found here : https://www.openfabrics.org/downloads/Windows/v3.2/